# "Isn't it?" vs. "isn't she?"

Tags: pronouns

1. That is the woman who married Tony, isn't it?
2. That is the woman who married Tony, isn't she?

Are both sentences correct?

If they are, what is the difference in meaning?

Comment: 1. *isn't it?* referring to the sentence as a whole, *isn't it correct that...*  2. *isn't she* referring to the sentence subject, *isn't she the...* This is just my best guess.

Comment: In Standard English, tag questions always mimic the main question. "That is ... isn't it?" "She is ... isn't she?". There are dialects where the standard tag-question is "isn't it" no matter what the main question is.

Comment: @AndrewLeach There's a reason (see MegaMark above) why, it's not axiomatic.

Comment: @Kris Yes: we both said the same thing.

Comment: See also http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/isn%27t_it_so

Answer (score 2):

Compare:

> Is/isn't *that* the woman who married Tony? (Ans: Yes, *it* is.)

with

> Is/isn't *she* the one who married Tony? (Ans: Yes, *she* is.)

In the first sentence, *that* is genderless, so the response is *it*. Similarly, *That's the one...* is referred to with an *it*.

*That* can refer to gendered or plural things, but when you refer back to *that*, you will use *it*.

> - Is *that* Marilyn Monroe? Yes, *it* is.
> - Is *that* the Rockettes? Yes, *it* is.

*That's (x), isn't it?* employs the same principle.

Comment: That much effort isn't quite necessary, isn't always the case, nor is it always possible to parse this way. The ***it*** is supposed to refer back to a "fact," but even that's not mostly the case, it's the existential *it* as far as the speaker's subconscious usage is concerned.

Comment: @Kris, note that medica's answer is both correct and comprehensive to the AmE speaker because we don't have the "existential it" the way BrE speakers do. So "... isn't it?" (without a specific, genderless antecedent) sounds quaintly British to us, innit?

Comment: @DanBron Quaint because as an idiom, it's essentially a Britishism.

Comment: @DanBron - Thank you for that. I am always forgetting to include that I can only speak for AmE, which does, indeed, limit my answer.